# How to get random foreign key in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle

After creating all tables in SQL Developer I need to fill them with at least 10000 entries. I had no problem with tables than had zero FK.
How can I get random values from other tables?

select rand() doesn't work in this statement. but max() does.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NAPOLNI_ARTIKEL 
(
  ST_ARTIKLOV IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 10000 
) AS 
  naziv VARCHAR2(25);
  opis VARCHAR2(25);
  model VARCHAR2(10);
  cena FLOAT(2);
  gar INTEGER;
  ddv INTEGER;
  tip INTEGER;
CURSOR c1 IS
  SELECT id_dobavitelj
  FROM dobavitelj;
BEGIN
FOR rndx IN c1 LOOP
  FOR st IN 1..ST_ARTIKLOV LOOP
    naziv := 'naziv';
    naziv := naziv ||' '|| TO_CHAR(st);
    opis := 'opis';
    opis := opis ||' '|| TO_CHAR(st);
    model := 'model';
    model := model ||' '|| TO_CHAR(st);

    cena := dbms_random.value(1.25,230.0);

    SELECT NVL(RAND(id_garancija),1)
    INTO gar
    FROM garancija;

    SELECT NVL(RAND(id_ddv),1)
    INTO ddv
    FROM DDV;

    SELECT NVL(RAND(id_tip),1)
    INTO tip
    FROM tip;

    INSERT INTO ARTIKEL(ID_ARTIKLA, NAZIV, OPIS, MODEL, CENA, TIP_ID_TIP, DOBAVITELJ_ID_DOBAVITELJ, GARANCIJA_ID_GARANCIJE, DDV_ID_DDV) VALUES (st, naziv, opis, model, cena, tip, rndx, gar, ddv);
  END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END NAPOLNI_ARTIKEL;
```

```
   * id_artikla INTEGER NOT NULL ,
   * naziv      VARCHAR2 (25) NOT NULL ,
     opis       VARCHAR2 (25) ,
   * model      VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL ,
   * cena FLOAT (2) NOT NULL ,
 F * Tip_id_tip               INTEGER NOT NULL ,
 F * Dobavitelj_id_dobavitelj INTEGER NOT NULL ,
 F   Garancija_id_garancije   INTEGER ,
 F * DDV_id_ddv               INTEGER NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pick a random value from a table you can use a subquery ordered randomly, and then pick the first row from that:

```
SELECT id_garancija
INTO gar
FROM (
  SELECT id_garancija
  FROM garancija
  ORDER BY dbms_random.value
)
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

With a lot of data you could also use [the `sample()` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2065953) to avoid having to find and order all values from the table:

```
SELECT id_garancija
INTO gar
FROM garancija
SAMPLE(1)
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

You can set the sample size based on the size of the table; with 10000 rows you might be able to use 0.1, for example. You can read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e16638/optimops.htm#i79194).

If you're populating your parent and child tables at the same time you could consider the `INSERT ALL` syntax to insert into multiple tables simultaneously, using the same values (eg from a sequence) consistently, rather than looking them up again later. It looks like you want random combinations of foreign keys though, so that might not be helpful here.